# Find a point n distance away from a specified point in a given direction

Tags: trigonometry

I'm waaay over my head here. Basically, I have a point (x, y) and a direction in degrees; I need to find a point that in n distance away from the given point in the specified direction.

I've tried looking up similar issues but everything is beyond my level of comprehension. Could somebody try to explain how I'd go about calculating this in as simple of terms as possible?

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, most libraries compute $\sin,\cos$ in radians, so you will need to convert your angle from degrees to radians. $d °$ corresponds to ${\pi \over 180} d$ radians.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let your point $(x, y)$ be $A$.

You gotta find the point a distance $n$ away at a given angle. Let $B(x_1,y_1)$ be your required point.. The easiest way to solve this, is to break it into *components* along the x and y axes.

By simple trigonometry:

[image]

$x_1 = x + n\cos\theta$
$y_1 = y + n\sin\theta$

Where $\theta$ is the angle given to you.

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta$ is the angle between the direction and the positive direction of the $x$ axis, and $x_{new},y_{new}$ be the coordinates of the point you are looking for then:

$x_{new}=x+n\cos(\theta)\\y_{new}=y+n\sin(\theta)$

Comment: @RossMillikan The problem statement says $n$ distance away.

Comment: @RossMillikan English is not my first language, thanks.